# Why is this python parsing script get exponentially slower the further down in the file list it goes?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a folder of a couple of thousand json files all of which are the same size. I wrote this script to parse each file and create a data frame. The script blazes through parsing these at the beginning and then gets slower the further it goes into the file list. Is there an error in the code somewhere that could be causing this?

```
import os
import json


data2 = {
  "id": [],
  "amount": [],
  "createdate": [],
  "dealname": [],
  "dealstage": [],
  "last_source": [],
  "first_source": [],
  "is_closed": [],
  "is_closed_won": [],
  "last_modified_date": [],
  "landing_site": [],
  "type_of_deal": [],
  "pipeline": [],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data2)


def read_json(filename: str) -> dict:
    try:
        with open("json" + "/" + filename, "r") as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
    except:
        raise Exception(f"Reading {filename} file encountered an error")

    return data

for file in os.listdir("json"):
    print(file)
    data = read_json(filename=file)

    results = data['results']

    for i in results:
        if "id" in i:
            id = i["id"]
        else:
            id = None
        if "amount" in i["properties"]:
            amount = i["properties"]["amount"]
        else:
            amount = None
        if "createdate" in i["properties"]:
            createdate = i["properties"]["createdate"]
        else:
            createdate = None
        if "dealname" in i["properties"]:
            dealname = i["properties"]["dealname"]
        else:
            dealname = None
        if "dealstage" in i["properties"]:
            dealstage = i["properties"]["dealstage"]
        else:
            dealstage = None
        if "hs_analytics_latest_source" in i["properties"]:
            last_source = i["properties"]["hs_analytics_latest_source"]
        else:
            last_source = None
        if "hs_analytics_source" in i["properties"]:
            first_source = i["properties"]["hs_analytics_source"]
        else:
            first_source = None
        if "hs_is_closed" in i["properties"]:
            is_closed = i["properties"]["hs_is_closed"]
        else:
            is_closed = None
        if "hs_is_closed_won" in i["properties"]:
            is_closed_won = i["properties"]["hs_is_closed_won"]
        else:
            is_closed_won = None
        if "hs_lastmodifieddate" in i["properties"]:
            last_modified_date = i["properties"]["hs_lastmodifieddate"]
        else:
            last_modified_date = None
        if "ip__shopify__landing_site" in i["properties"]:
            landing_site = i["properties"]["ip__shopify__landing_site"]
        else:
            landing_site = None
        if "type_of_deal" in i["properties"]:
            type_of_deal = i["properties"]["type_of_deal"]
        else:
            type_of_deal = None
        if "pipeline" in i["properties"]:
            pipeline = i["properties"]["pipeline"]
        else:
            pipeline = None
        all_list = [id, amount, createdate, dealname, dealstage, last_source, first_source, is_closed, is_closed_won, last_modified_date, landing_site, type_of_deal, pipeline]
        df.loc[len(df)] = all_list

df.to_csv("historical.csv")
```

Comment: As far as I know pandas has to copy the whole dataframe when appending a row to it. This isn't a particular efficient operation.

Comment: How large is your dataset and how much RAM do you have? I would monitor the usage and see if there data is being written to swap / disk causing the slowdown. It might help to chunk the dataset or reduce memory footprint on the machine this is being run on.

Comment: Any reason you don't use pd.read_json when you loop through the files? Maybe figure out a way to manipulate the data using read_json and then  use pd.concat() onto your empty dataframe for each one? I'm not sure that would be faster, but native pandas usually works best.

Comment: I think you've over thought it,, your fastest solution would be create a list of dicts/json (dict per record) then use pd.DataFrame(list_of_records). With that you should even be able to get rid of all the parsing lines you have as if a key is missing pandas should fill with nan. If you get extra columns clean up the final df with df.drop(columns=['extra', 'columns' ])